# How do I find the UNIX timestamp for a specific HH:MM time given a UTC offset in PHP?

Tags: php, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

I have a list of UTC offsets as integers in seconds. For example -36000 for -10 hours.
How can I find the UNIX timestamp for say, 10:00PM at the location with that offset in PHP.

PS: It's not homework

Thanks

Comment: What you really want is to simply make a time object in the given timezone, e.g. `$time = new DateTime('10pm', $timezone)`, then format that as a UNIX timestamp. The problem is figuring out the correct `$timezone`. Offsets aren't good as timezone modifiers, since they carry no information about DST and such things, which is why PHP uses timezone designators like "Asia/Tokyo" instead of numeric offsets. If you can change your timezone information to this standard, the problem is easy.

Comment: Since I'm getting into an argument with @Wh1T3h4Ck5 here, please confirm that your question is really what you're literally asking: It's 10pm at the location with the offset -36000, and you want to know what UNIX timestamp that translates to? Not that it's 10pm *here*, and you want to know the UNIX timestamp at the location which has an offset of -36000?

Answer (score -1):

new DateTime($yourTimestamp, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

should be fine